# Can I replace fragment layout outside of the fragment activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, sharedpreferences

I am working on app and i have issue when i click on menu button favorite list open but i want access that from main activity is that possible like this in image: [image]

Comment: do you mean you want to open favorite list from main list ?

Comment: yes sir that's i want

Answer (score 2):

if you want to move from list to item details you can pass your data in the adapter for RecyclerView .

```
  @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ListAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, FavoriteActivity.class);
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("yourdata", yourdata);
                intent.putExtras(bundle);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
```

if you use ListView you can try

```
your_listview.setOnItemClickListener { parent, view, position, id ->   

  Intent intent = new Intent(context, FavoriteActivity.class);
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("yourdata", yourdata);
                intent.putExtras(bundle);
                context.startActivity(intent);
 }
```

in `FavoritActivity` you can set this data by :

`String data= getIntent().getExtras().getString("yourdata");`

i hope i understood right .

Comment: sorry sir but that's not my question.

Answer (score 0):

Add to your list item model one more variable and use it.
For example:

```
boolean isFavorite;
```

When you create constructor all items `false`, when you click star to list, make your item's flag to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

this code i use to open favt activity but this is use for same activity with menu button but i want to open favt fragment from main activity.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_favorites:

            favListFragment = new FavoriteListFragment();
            switchContent(favListFragment, FavoriteListFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID);

            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void switchContent(Fragment fragment, String tag) {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    while (fragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate());

    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager
                .beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment, tag);
        //Only FavoriteListFragment is added to the back stack.
        if (!(fragment instanceof ProductListFragment)) {
            transaction.addToBackStack(tag);
        }
        transaction.commit();
        contentFragment = fragment;
    }
}
```